# How to cooperate in order to build good questions before asking them?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I have some questions in my mind (history questions in this case) but I'm not really sure they would be very welcomed in the form I got them at this moment so I don't think it's a good idea to ask them at this moment.

I would like to share those question ideas so that others can see them and refine them or to suggest improvements. Sure, I like getting points, but I like even more the idea that someone takes a question idea from me and grows it into a really valuable question and ask that question before I do, so I'm very happy with someone else "taking" "my points" in such a manner, because the collective knowledge is the thing that really matters.

The best that I can think of is a Wikipedia-like page that all the users can edit and where they can present their question ideas. Each section of the page for another idea. Then the users can use those sections to discuss the idea. When the sections grow to large, move them into sub-pages.

At this moment, my question ideas are something like this - some of them I might grow into meaningful questions, some others I will abandon:

- When did stoneware become widespread (in Europe, Middle East and Asia)?
- How expensive were the glass vessels comparing to ceramic vessels in Ancient Rome and in the Middle Ages?
- What prevented the glazed ceramic to become widespread and prevalent in the  Claudian period and after? (Vitreous enamel#History - Production is thought to have come to a peak in the Claudian period and persisted for some three hundred years, though archaeological evidence for this technique is limited to some forty vessels or vessel fragments)
- Were the Amphora used by the Romans coated in glazing? Because without glazing, the earthenware is not suitable for holding liquids, and they used Amphora for storing/transporting oil, which is a liquid.
- Is the Rio Grande Glaze Ware (pre-columbian) nonporous, like any glazed ceramic?
- What did the pre-columbian Americans use for storing liquids since their pottery was only non-glazed (and therefore porous) earthenware - (except Rio Grande Glaze Ware)?
- How quickly is the water leaving an unglazed earthenware vessel anyways?

I just got a lot of down votes [for asking a notepad/multiple public drafts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/301830/idea-a-notepad-or-clipboard-just-for-questions-to-be-asked-later) but I think this question deserves attention - how to grow good questions together?

Comment: What would be against it if you host those questions on your github repo and link to it from your profile?

Comment: The chat can be used if you need guidance, but you can edit your question when its post. A closure is never final if you can salvage the question. Keep in mind we cant guide everyone, and reviewing something before its posted as no value, we already have all the tool to review question

Comment: @rene - that means making hundreds and thousands of individual pages for the people to crawl, while on a Wikipedia-like platform, the users can add together (and then discuss) tens and even hundreds of incipient questions in a single page. A page like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Fructibus/Questions) but having multiple users starting questions in it. There might be better ways to do it but this looks quite good to me.

Comment: @yagmoth555 - sure, the chat is a very good feature, but on a Wikipedia-like page, the community can work at a single question for days and weeks without rush, collecting all the ideas about it in a single place. Sure, a question can be salvaged and improved, but if it doesn't have a good start, it usually remains neglected as a part of the potential answerers won't come back to check it. In the same time a well made question from the moment it's asked has much better chances to get good answers. Maybe it would also help getting better answers too, as the users can prepare the answers in time.

Comment: If you like wikipedia with all the tools, just use that. SE is a Q/A site with questions and answers. Not a collection of brain-dumps that need to mature first.

Comment: Sorry to disagree but the chat is also a collection of brain dumps and it's part of SE and I believe it's not impossible for the SE to to open a space on Wikipedia or on Wikia (for free) and to invite the users to mature incipient questions there. A cooperation between Wikipedia and SE doesn't look unnatural to me. The users already use one platform to improve the other and the other way around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I've wanted help formulating a question, I've found that a site's chat room to be a useful resource.  I can explain what I'm trying to do, share my draft, get feedback, and improve it before asking.  You can post the draft somewhere, for example in a gist, or write directly in chat.  I've seen both work.

A few sites have a question sandbox on meta ([example](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4835/28)) -- usually one meta question to which people post draft questions, get feedback in comments, edit, and ultimately delete (after they either ask or abandon the question).  If you want to propose a sandbox, you'd need to do that on the specific community.

It sounds like you're looking for something bigger -- you want to post many draft questions and have the community critique and edit them for you.  That's not really how this works.  The community does those things for *actual questions on the site*, and is usually willing to do it for the *occasional question from somebody just getting started or trying to work out something complicated*, but you shouldn't expect any community to thoroughly review all of your questions before you post them.

If you have a question, ask it and fix any issues that are raised as you go.  If you have a particularly thorny question-composition problem, ask for help with that specific question in chat or via a sandbox (if your site has a sandbox).  Beyond that, no there's no "safety net" that will spare you from downvotes if your questions need work -- just a community that wants good questions and that will probably upvote (or remove downvotes) when questions become good questions.

Comment: Thanks for the very good answer. What I was thinking about was a separate such sandbox for each SE site, of course, not a single one for all the sites where to make a tangle-jungle of questions. I wasn't thinking about the community cleaning the mess in my own mental dumps but about a place to actually work together and also as a pool of incipient ideas that I would also like to browse and to improve. This is nothing about being safe from downvotes, I just wish that ideas mature completely before launching, and sometimes that exceeds one's capacity to do it (it's mostly about time-energy).

Comment: I had no idea that SE sandboxes exist, what's the best place for starting to learn about it?

Comment: I edited in a link to a sandbox example.  The post there explains how it works.  Worldbuilding built on the work of other sites (not sure which; I wasn't very involved in this), and others will presumably build on us in turn.